# How to start executable with realtime priority?

Tags: windows, cmd, scheduling

So I try this on windows 8.1:

```
start /low cmd
```

And I get cmd process with low priority. But when I do:

```
start /realtime cmd
```

I get new cmd process with high priority.

Is there a way to get realtime without setting it manually?
Also, can I somehow set desired priority from the code of my application, maybe WinApi or something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works when you are executing `start` as an administrator.

Technically, you need the `SeIncreaseBasePriorityPrivilege`, which an administrator normally has.
If you don't, it looks like albeit I couldn't find any documentation about that fact, that you are silently reverted to a priority that is still viable with the calling account.

I doubt that Win32 will help, as the same restrictions surely apply.

Answer (score 3):

To make realtime work from CMD or Process Lasso without admin rights, it needs to be changed in:

secpol.msc > Local Policies > User Rights Assignment > Increase Scheduling Priority > Properties > Add user or group > Write down "Everyone" > check name > OK

I needed the solution to launch VBS script running CMD with priority set command in background, I couldn't open VBS script as admin.

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO Setting process priority    
wmic process where name="process.exe" CALL setpriority "Realtime"
```

A solution is to start the process as you are, but then run the above batch script file as administrator.

Comment: This didn't work for me. The command seemed to succeed but the priority was unchanged, regardless of its level. (\\MACHINE\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_Process.Handle="7972")->setpriority()
Method execution successful.
Out Parameters:
instance of __PARAMETERS
{
        ReturnValue = 0;
};